# Unequal Loan Repayments

Tags: calculation

I am struggling with this question below.

> Present Value = 100000
>
> Interest =12.25% per annum
>
> Number of months = 60
>
> Payments =?

Payments increase by 15% per annum.

Calculate the PMT for all years.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem in some course and not an issue of personal finance.

Comment: The question might be homework, I agree, 100%. But the process has relevance to personal finance, and especially in light of Chris' answer, I'd vote to have it stay.

Answer (score 3):

A method of calculation is shown here:-

Investopedia - [Calculating The Present And Future Value Of Annuities](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/03/101503.asp)

Specifically, the section: *Calculating the Present Value of an Ordinary Annuity*.

The example shown calculates the present (or initial) value of a 5 year loan given annual payments of $1,000 with an effective interest rate of 5%.  By discounting the future payments according to the interest rate the present value is calculated to be $4,329.48.

[image]

In your question the initial value is known and the payments are to be calculated.

```
p = initial loan value = 100,000
n = compounding periods per year = 12
r = effective annual interest rate = 12.25% = 0.1225
i = monthly interest rate = (1 + r)^(1/n) - 1 = 0.00967638
d = initial payment amount
```

The present value of the loan is equal to the sum of the discounted payments for each year.

[image]

The payments for the first year are 1,688.56 increasing annually by 15% thereafter.

The calculation can also be generalised and converted into a formula for `d`.

```
y = number of years = 5
q = annual percentage increase in payments = 15% = 0.15
```

[image]

Text form

```
d = ((1 + i)^(12 * y) * p * 
    (i * (2 + i) * (1 + i + i^2) * (2 + i * (2 + i)) * 
       (1 + i * (1 + i)^2 * (2 + i)) * (3 + i * (3 + i)) - q))/
  ((2 + i) * (1 + i + i^2) * (2 + i * (2 + i)) * 
    (1 + i * (1 + i)^2 * (2 + i)) * (3 + i * (3 + i)) * 
    ((1 + i)^(12 y) - (1 + q)^y))
```